# Syntax error on comonent proxy

Tags: reactjs

I tried to defined a component like

```
const Td = props => <td style={{"width":"33%", "border": "1px solid black"}} {...props}>
```

but got

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: E:/MyStuff/Project2017/ReactReduxStarterKit/src/components/MainPage/FormTable/TodoList/TodoList.js: Unexpected token, expected }

const Td = props => <td style={{"width":"33%", "border": "1px solid black"}} {...props}>

class _TodoList extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
 |                     ^
```

I can not find out what was wrong with the statement and all {, } are in pair...

Maybe I need some escape?

thanks

Comment: Replace comma with semicolon.: <td style={{"width":"33%"; "border": "1px solid black"}}

Comment: The `<td ...>` is unclosed. Add a slash like `<td .../>`.

Comment: Yes. That was the problem but what I confused was that I tried to define a "<td>". I thought I should not include "</td>" but the syntax require it and surprisely work does need that. Thanks!